# wordpress hybrid theme centralize footer

Tags: wordpress

the footer in hybrid simple theme is aligned to left and i want it in the cenre Please help

Comment: Try harder, then come back in 3 months if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `#footer { text-align: center; }` to your CSS file? I tried it [on the demo site](http://themehybrid.com/demo/hybrid/) and it seems to work. The `.copyright` element floats to the left, so you probably want to remove that too to get everything in the center.